# How do i call out variable from a function in another function?-Python3

Tags: python-3.x

```
def run():
    rundecision=input("What do you want to do? calculate distance(d),pace(p) time(t):")

if rundecision in ['distance', 'd']:
    pace()
    time()
distance=calculator(distance=None,pace=pacetotal,time=timetotal)
return str(distance) + paceunit

print (run())
```

my pace() is below where pace total is defined and called out above.

```
def pace():
    while True:
        pacemin=input("Enter what pace you want to run/ you ran in :00(min):")#user pace in min
        pacesec=input("Enter what pace you want to run/ you ran in :00(secs):")#user pace in sec
        try:
            pacemin=int(pacemin)
            pacesec=int(pacesec)
            if  0 <= pacemin <= 59 and 0 <= pacesec <=59:
                pacetotal=(to_seconds(pacemin,'min')) + (to_seconds(pacesec,'s'))
                pacetotal=int(pacetotal)
                return pacetotal
                break
)
```

This is my error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "minicapstonev2.py", line
>   188, in 
>       print (run())   File "minicapstonev2.py", line 185, in run
>       distance=calculator(distance=None,pace=pacetotal,time=timetotal)

NameError: name 'pacetotal' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign the return values of your functions to a variable that u can use:

```
if rundecision in ['distance', 'd']:
    pacetotal = pace() # pace returns the seconds
    timetotal = time() # this should also return the value for your next computation
distance=calculator(distance=None,pace=pacetotal,time=timetotal)
return str(distance) + paceunit
```

You did not supply the `time()` function, but if it is similar to pace this should work.

---

Edit due to question in comments:

Some variations on how to approach returnvalues and your program:

```
# Different ways to return something from a function
def ModifyGivenDict(di , li):
    # do some calculations
    di["milesPerHour"] = 42
    li.append(999)

def ReturnAValue(x):
    return x ** x

def ReturnMultipleValues(x):
    return [x * u for u in range(20)]

def ReturnTuple(x,y):
    return (x,y,x * y,x ** y,y ** x,"someValue")

d = {"Round1": 496 }
l = [2,3,4,5,"Hurray"]
a = ModifyGivenDict(d,l)
print(d)

k = ReturnAValue(22)
print(k)

i = ReturnMultipleValues(22)
print(i)

h = ReturnTuple(4,7)
print(h)


# OOP aproach
class Timings: 
    @staticmethod
    def toSeconds(text):
        """Understands up to '12:18:24.3545' - returns a floatvalue of seconds"""
        t = [0,0] + text.split(":") # prefix with 2 * 0 if only "22" or "1:22" is given
        t[-1] = float(t[-1])        # make last elements to float
        t[-2] = int(t[-2]) * 60       # make integer minutes into seconds
        t[-3] = int(t[-3]) * 60 * 60    # make integer hours into seconds

        return sum(t)

    @staticmethod
    def toMeters(distance):
        """Understands '255.23 meters'"""
        converterDict = {'mile':1609.34, 'mi':1609.34, 'km':1000, 'kilometer':1000, 
                         'y':0.9144, 'yard':0.9144, 'meter':1, 'm':1}
        dist,unit = distance.split(" ")
        dist = float(dist)
        unit = unit.rstrip("s").strip().lower()
        return dist * converterDict[unit]

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.laps = {}
        self.lap = 0

    def addLap(self, minutesColonSeconds, distance):
        t = self.toSeconds(minutesColonSeconds)
        m = self.toMeters(distance)
        self.laps[self.lap] = {"time":t, "distance":m}
        self.lap += 1

    def printLaps(self):
        print("Results for " + self.name,sep="\t")
        print("{:<14} {:<14} {:<14} {:<14} {:<14} {:<14} {:<14}".format(
              "lap","m","s","m/s", "total time", "total dist","speed"))

        tm = 0
        tt = 0

        # you could also use an orderedDict from collections
        for k in sorted(self.laps.keys()):
            m = self.laps[k]["distance"]
            t = self.laps[k]["time"]
            tm +=m
            tt += t
            print("{:<14} {:<14} {:<14} {:<14} {:<14} {:<14} {:<14}".format(
                   k,m,t,round(m / t,2), tt,tm,round(tm/tt,2)))


def inputTime(text):
    while True:
        i = input(text)
        try:
            t = [0,0] + i.split(":")
            sec = float(t[-1])
            min = int(t[-2])
            hou = int(t[-3])
            if sec+min*60+hou*60*60 <= 0:
                raise ValueError
            return i
        except (ValueError,EOFError):
            print("Wrong input! Use  '1:12:23.99' for hour:minute:second.partials")


def inputDistance(text):
    while True:
        t = input(text)
        try:
            dis,un = t.split()
            dis = float(dis)
            return t
        except:
            print("Wrong input. Use: '23 km' - or: meter, mile(s), yard(s), m, mi, y")

print("\nClassaproach\n\n")

timing = Timings("Just Me")

while True:
    dis = inputDistance("What distance did you cover?")
    tim = inputTime("In what time?")
    timing.addLap(tim,dis)
    timing.printLaps()
```

Output (edited to better fit here):

```
{'Round1': 496, 'milesPerHour': 42}
341427877364219557396646723584
[0, 22, 44, 66, 88, 110, 132, 154, 176, 198, 220, 242, 264, 286,
 308, 330, 352, 374, 396, 418]
(4, 7, 28, 16384, 2401, 'someValue')

Classaproach


What distance did you cover?100 m
In what time?12.02
Results for Just Me
lap       m              s          m/s        total time     total dist     speed
0         100.0          12.02      8.32       12.02          100.0          8.32
What distance did you cover?20 km
In what time?2:0:01
Results for Just Me
lap       m              s          m/s        total time     total dist     speed
0         100.0          12.02      8.32       12.02          100.0          8.32
1         20000.0        7201.0     2.78       7213.02        20100.0        2.79
What distance did you cover?5 mi
In what time?1:1:1
Results for Just Me
lap       m              s          m/s        total time     total dist     speed
0         100.0          12.02      8.32       12.02          100.0          8.32
1         20000.0        7201.0     2.78       7213.02        20100.0        2.79
2         8046.7         3661.0     2.2        10874.02       28146.7        2.59
What distance did you cover?120 km
In what time?1:02:00
Results for Just Me
lap       m              s          m/s        total time     total dist     speed
0         100.0          12.02      8.32       12.02          100.0          8.32
1         20000.0        7201.0     2.78       7213.02        20100.0        2.79
2         8046.7         3661.0     2.2        10874.02       28146.7        2.59
3         120000.0       3720.0     32.26      14594.02       148146.7       10.15
What distance did you cover?
        ...
```

Comment: yes, this was super helpful, i spent 1.5 days (programming newbie)trying to solve on my own.  the paceunit is still giving me an error. do i have to define paceunit as a standalone function to call it the way i have it above in the return statement. paceunit is part of the pace function

Comment: @ladel paceunit is 'm' for meters? as your program converts any inputs to secods (and distances probably to some other baseunit), I would probably hardcode it...

Comment: pace unit is a list  of units that the user gets to input. its define under pace() while True:
        paceunit=input("Enter unit of your run pace mile, meter, yards or kilometer:")
        try:
            if paceunit in [ 'mile','mi','km','kilometer','y','yards','yard','meters','m']:
                break
        except:
            print("your pace unit is entered incorrectly please enter any one of these units shown.  'mile','mi','km','kilometer','y','yards','yard','meters','m'")#exception to reengage user to enter the right units
    return str(pacetotal)+ str(paceunit)

Comment: @ladel review my edit, copy it, add print-statements to debug it and try to "groke" it :) - hth

Comment: thanks for the help. will review and play with your code.